Bank heist comedy (60's or 70's) - bailing out the mastermind
I watched a movie when I was a young boy about 25 years ago on a German TV channel. It was dubbed from English. I don't know the names of any actors.
Here is all the info I recall from the movie:
Movie info:
Funny bank robbery movie, color, sufficiently old-looking, hence I estimate it to be from the 60's or 70's. 
Plot:
The movie starts with members of the team arriving in some remote cabin only to find that the mastermind is missing, but he left the plans for robbing a bank. They decide to make the heist without him. After the robbery they find out that he is in jail and decide to bail him out with the stolen money. One team member is against the plan but he is thrown onto a truck with pigs and then forced to help nevertheless. Another team member poses as a philanthropic millionaire to bail the mastermind out. The whole setting is in a small town or village with a single Sheriff in rural America.
Actors:
There is no main actor since the whole movie is about the group executing the robbery. The guy who gets thrown onto the truck with pigs is young, tall and skinny, has brown mullet-style hair and is, I think the explosives guy. The lock-picker is an older guy, around 50-60, with gray hair. I don't remember the other team members any more, but I think all of them were male.
Some memorable scenes:

The mastermind gets pulled over by the Sheriff and is arrested for a petty crime (I don't remember what, could have been speeding or wrong parking) which he might not even have committed, since the Sheriff seemed to have known about his identity and used any phony reason to arrest him.
The team members arrive mostly by train. The first scenes show how they get off the train and arrive in a very remote location, there are hills and dried out prairie / desert. One of the members carries an old doctor-bag with lock-picking stuff. None of them knows one another. They initially mistrust each other when they arrive in the cabin and see the plans for the robbery.
One of the guys is thrown onto a truck with pigs. I think the scene is repeated at the end of the film again for a different reason, which I don't remember any more.


Please read tag info before using tags. Heist is a title, not a genre. Also, please review this post for info on asking good ID questions: http://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/identify-this-movie/info

@Catija Thanks for pointing this out to me. I have improved the post and added more information.

Thanks for the info, that's much better. It sounds a bit like Disorganized Crime from 1989, but some things are a bit off (the year, for one).

Sounds like one of the Olsen Gang films, which seem to start with their leader in jail from their previous exploits. https://www.themoviedb.org/collection/11118-olsen-bandens-jubil-umssamling?language=en

@Walt You are amazing! It must be Disorganized Crime. I seem to have been misled by the rural setting and crappy cars to believe that it was the 60/70's. I might be off about some other things too in the plot, but I have only a very vague recollection of it. However some youtube trailers I have found after your tip confirmed that it is indeed that movie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqxpZ7CUF-o . Thank you so much. Please add an answer so that I can accept it.

@dbugger Thanks for the tip - but it definitely wasn't the Olsen Gang. I would have recognized those actors. Those movies were known quite well all over Europe at that time.

Sure, no problem. Glad you found it.

The 1989 comedy Disorganized Crime with Lou Diamond Phillips, Corbin Bernsen and Ed O'Neill, 

The story begins in a small town in western Montana where New Jersey based bank robber Frank Salazar has been hiding out from the law after a series of bank robberies in Newark. Upon realizing that the local bank contains a large amount of cash, Salazar recruits four former accomplices to come to town and help him rob the bank. Before they can arrive, however, two New Jersey detectives (George Denver and Bill Lonigan) catch up with Salazar, arrest him, and extradite him back to New Jersey. But Salazar soon escapes and becomes hopelessly lost in the Montana wilderness as he flees Denver and Lonigan's custody.

The four robbers meet in a remote cabin, and there are a couple of scenes where people are forced to take a ride in a truck full of pig manure.



